# Upload and reference files in Docker - ASP.NET Core

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm learning Docker and I dockerized my ASP.NET Core Web API.

The problem is uploading files/images (e.g. user profile images) to Docker, and referencing them.

On my local dev machine, I upload the files to say `C:/users/myname/projectname/profileImage`. I store the image name and extension my database table, and at runtime, I combine the image path and `image-name.extension` from the database table.

How can I do this in Docker containers (the path directory part and referencing it)? I don't want store the images/files in `wwwroot` of the project because these files/images need to be private.

Answer (score 0):

The way I sorted this is by using Azure File Share (or you can use other if you prefer). We a mount file system within a pod and read/write to and from it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-csi-files-storage-provision